# SetSelectedRange Spread.NET javascript issue

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, farpoint-spread

I'm trying to add functionality to Spread.NET control where it will permit a hold shift-click to select a range of cells in ASP.
I'm creating the event onActiveCellChanged to call the selectRange function on execution

```
   var shiftPressed = false;
   var newSelect = true;

   window.pageLoad = function init() {
       var ss = document.getElementById('<%=FpSpread1.ClientID %>');

       if (ss.addEventListener != null) {
           ss.addEventListener("ActiveCellChanged", selectRange(), false);
       } else if (ss.attachEvent != null) {
           ss.attachEvent("ActiveCellChanged", selectRange());
       }
       else {
           FpSpread1.onActiveCellChanged = selectRange;
       }
   }
```

Here is the selectRange function.

```
        function selectRange() {
            var ss = document.getElementById('<%=FpSpread1.ClientID %>');
            var swap;

            if (shiftPressed == true) {
                var initRow = document.getElementById('RowCoord').value;
                var initCol = document.getElementById('ColCoord').value;
                var SecRow = getRow();
                var SecCol = getCol();
                newSelect = false;

                var rCount = Math.abs(SecRow - initRow) + 1;
                var cCount = Math.abs(SecCol - initCol) + 1;

                if (initRow > SecRow)
                    initRow = SecRow;

                if (initCol > SecCol)
                    initCol = SecCol;

                //alert(initRow + ' ' + initCol);
                alert(initRow + ' ' + initCol + ' ' + rCount + ' ' + cCount);
                ss.SetSelectedRange(initRow, initCol, rCount, cCount);

            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('RowCoord').value = 0;
                document.getElementById('ColCoord').value = 0;
                newSelect = true;
            }
        }
```

And this is how I'm determining whether shift is being held.

```
        function aKeyDown(event) {

            if (event.keyCode == 16) {

                shiftPressed = true;
                var col = getCol();
                var row = getRow();

                if (newSelect) {
                    document.getElementById('RowCoord').value = row;
                    document.getElementById('ColCoord').value = col;
                }
            }
        }

        function aKeyUp(event) {

            if (event.keyCode == 16) {
                shiftPressed = false;
            }
        }

        function getRow() {
            var ss = document.getElementById('<%=FpSpread1.ClientID %>');
            ret = ss.ActiveRow;

            if (ret == undefined)
                ret = ss.GetActiveRow;

            return ret;
        }

        function getCol() {
            var ss = document.getElementById('<%=FpSpread1.ClientID %>');
            ret = ss.ActiveCol;

            if (ret == undefined)
                ret = ss.GetActiveCol;

            return ret;
        }
```

The `SetSelectedRange` in the select range function will work if my initial cell is a,1.  However, if it's any other cell, it'll select the entire row and column.

Here is my `<div>` tag:

```
<FarPoint:FpSpread onkeydown="aKeyDown(event)" onkeyup="aKeyUp(event)" ID="FpSpread1"...
```

In image 1, My initial cell was (a,3) and I held shift and clicked on (b,4)

In image 2, it works. As long as I start at cell (a,1)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to parseInt the row and column values.

```
function getRow() {
        var ss = document.getElementById(spd);
        ret = ss.ActiveRow;

        if (ret == undefined)
            ret = ss.GetActiveRow();

        return parseInt(ret);
    }

    function getCol() {
        var ss = document.getElementById(spd);
        ret = ss.ActiveCol;

        if (ret == undefined)
            ret = ss.GetActiveCol();

        return parseInt(ret);
    }
```